# How to deploy separate team projects to one server

Tags: tfs

Using **TFS 2018**, I have a need to deploy (individually) different team projects to the same target server. Until update 2 is released, [it is not possible to share deployment groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160477/tfs-2018-how-to-share-deployment-group).

However, there must be a way to deploy different team projects to the same server.

My thought was maybe I have to create one release agent for each project, since I cannot share a deployment pool. However, I read a [TechNet post from 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34753.configure-multiple-buildrelease-agents-in-single-build-machinetfs-2015vs-team-services.aspx) that says

> It is recommended to limit the number of agents, in a build machine,
>   to the number of CPU cores it has.

Whether the article was being ambiguous and means build - or - release agents, or only means build agents only, I don't know. OK, my target server has 4 CPUs and I need the option to deploy any number of individual, independent Team Projects to the same server, so it's starting to look like creating a separate depolyment agent per team project is not going to be feasible.

Until update 2 is released it is not possible to share the same deployment group. My question is *how do I actually achieve this necessary outcome of independently deploying more than one Team Project to the same server?*

Please remember that I am restricted to TFS. *VSTS is not an option in my scenario*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That recommendation is really more for build servers. Build servers have very different requirements in terms of CPU/memory than release agents. Build agents are very memory and CPU intensive *while running builds*. You're not going to be running builds on your release agents.

The release agent is going to be idle the vast majority of the time. I don't see a problem with creating a second deployment group with a second agent install as a workaround until you can upgrade.

Comment: That sounds reassuring, but let's start increasing the number of projects that need to be deployed. What about five? What about 10? I'm not going to the point of absurdity, but over the next year, we're planning at least eight separate web/database projects to be housed on the same server.

Comment: @RandomHandle You have some options: 1) Don't use deployment groups. 2)  Keep everything in a single team project. 3) Upgrade to TFS 2018.2 ASAP.

Comment: #1 looks to be the sanest option. I've tested out WinRM (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm) and it appears to do the job.